# How to identify and list polytrees within a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) using R and igraph?

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am working with a directed acyclic graph (DAG) using R and the igraph package. In my DAG, the direction of edges goes from "leaves" to a "sink". The graph contains several sub-graphs which I believe to be polytrees and I would like to identify them programmatically.

Here's my graph:

```
library(igraph)
library(tidyverse)

edges <- tribble(
    ~from,  ~to,
    "G",    "E",
    "F",    "E",
    "E",    "C",
    "C",    "A",
    "H",    "D",
    "D",    "C",
    "D",    "B",
    "B",    "A")

g <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, directed = TRUE)
plot(g)
```

```
   A     G
  / \   /
 B  (C)-E
  \ /   \ 
  (D)    F 
   |
   H
```

In this DAG, I believe the sub-graph composed of nodes F, G, E, and C is a polytree, as well as the sub-graph composed of nodes H and D. In the first case, F and G are leaf nodes pointing to E, and E points to C. In the second case, H is a leaf node pointing to D.

This is what i tried:

```
# Identify the root nodes (vertices with no incoming edges)
roots <- V(g)[degree(g, mode = "in") == 0]$name

# Create a list to store the polytrees
polytrees <- list()

# For each root node, find all descendant nodes
for (root in roots) {
    # Start with just the root node
    nodes <- c(root)

    # As long as there are nodes to explore...
    while (length(nodes) > 0) {
        # Take the first node
        node <- nodes[1]

        # Find all out-neighbors (child nodes)
        neighbors <- neighbors(g, node, mode = "out")$name

        # Add the neighbors to the polytrees list (if they're not already there)
        polytrees[[root]] <- unique(c(polytrees[[root]], neighbors))

        # Add the neighbors to the list of nodes to explore (if they're not already there)
        nodes <- unique(c(nodes, neighbors))

        # Remove the current node from the list of nodes to explore
        nodes <- setdiff(nodes, node)
    }
}

# Print the polytrees
print(polytrees)
```

The expected output would be an ordered list of each polytree, starting from the anchoring node to the main DAG (nodes in parentheses), so for this DAG, there would be two sequences: C-E-F-G and D-H.

How can I identify such polytrees and output them in the expected format using R and igraph?

Comment: Why don't you take the edge C -> A into account in your first polytree?

Comment: Perhaps my understanding of a polytree isn't clear. What I'm looking for are the induced subgraphs that originate from the anchor (root) nodes C and D

Comment: If I understand your question, this is equivalent to enumerating _all_ undirected spanning trees. I suggest you indicate your interest at https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/1827 The level of user feedback will influence issue prioritization.

Comment: Note that igraph does already have `sample_spanning_tree()` for random sampling of spanning trees.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you for your suggestion. While I understand the concept of spanning trees, my goal is somewhat different. I'm looking for induced subgraphs from specific 'root' nodes (C and D in my case). These subgraphs are 'polytrees' where every node has a unique path to the root, and they don't necessarily include all nodes in the original graph. Spanning trees and polytrees have similarities but also key differences, particularly in handling edge direction and inclusion of all nodes

Answer (score 1):

With your `roots` and given `sinks <- c("C","D")`, we can try

```
sinks <- c("C", "D")

l <- lapply(
    roots,
    \(v) {
        sb <- subcomponent(g, v, "out")
        head(sb, which.max(names(sb) %in% sinks))
    }
)

tapply(
    l,
    sapply(l, tail, 1),
    \(v) {
        subgraph(g, unique(unlist(v)))
    }
)
```

which gives

```
$`4`
IGRAPH e9d2fae DN-- 4 3 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges from e9d2fae (vertex names):
[1] G->E F->E E->C

$`6`
IGRAPH e9d38d7 DN-- 2 1 --
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edge from e9d38d7 (vertex names):
[1] H->D
```

Comment: The solution is correct, but I need to automatically identify the root nodes (C and D). These are the points from which branches originate, like C that connects E, G, and F to the main graph, and D that starts a branch with H. How could I automate the detection of these nodes?"

Comment: @William but what is the criteria to identify nodes C and D?

Comment: Well, I think that Root nodes like 'C' and 'D' aren't defined solely by their degrees. The key characteristic is the structure stemming from these nodes. Specifically, a node is a 'root' of a polytree if its induced subgraph forms a tree - no cycles and one path from root to any node. While 'C' and 'E' share the same degree, 'C' is a root as it induces a tree, unlike 'E'. So, root nodes have incoming and outgoing edges, and their outgoing edges form a tree structure in the induced subgraph.